# Look like Promise.all() with mongoose query is as spending time as sequential await

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I'm trapped on `Promise.all` vs `await` in a mongoose query.

I try to benchmark between `async/await` and `Promise.all` and both of my code goes for the same spending time.

I provided some of my code. In the first section, I try to use promise.all and the last I try to use await and this is the result

```
sep: 2890.802ms
sep-await: 2409.150ms
```

```
console.time('sep')
  const [New, CreatingQuotation, CreatingInvoiceCoverage, CarChecking, Completed, Cancelled] = await Promise.all([
    this.where('State', 'new').countDocuments().exec(),
    this.where('State', 'creating_quotation').countDocuments().exec(),
    this.where('State', 'creation_invoice_coverage').countDocuments().exec(),
    this.where('State', 'car_checking').countDocuments().exec(),
    this.where('State', 'completed').countDocuments().exec(),
    this.where('State', 'cancelled').countDocuments().exec(),
  ])
  console.timeEnd('sep')


  console.time('sep-await')
  const NewX = await this.where('State', 'new').countDocuments().exec()
  const CreatingQuotationX = await this.where('State', 'creating_quotation').countDocuments().exec()
  const CreatingInvoiceCoverageX = await this.where('State', 'creation_invoice_coverage').countDocuments().exec()
  const CarCheckingX = await this.where('State', 'car_checking').countDocuments().exec()
  const CompletedX = await this.where('State', 'completed').countDocuments().exec()
  const CancelledX = await this.where('State', 'cancelled').countDocuments().exec()
  console.timeEnd('sep-await')
```

I think `Promise.all` should go faster than `await` for 5 times as expect. Please discuss why.

Comment: Looks like `exec` itself is sequential. Do you have some kind of connection pool?

Comment: @Bergi I'm not sure I really understand your question. but I think `exec` return Promise and I should work in this case.

Comment: Yes, I agree that it should work. The only reason why it would not that I can think of is that `exec()` doesn't start execution immediately but waits until the database connection (or some other resource) is idle.

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding of `Promise.all` and `async/await` is correct.

There is something happening in the background, maybe the `this.where` eventually ends in some kind of queue and component logic is executing just one by one anyway.

Can you also include more code so we can see what `this` context actually is?

---

Or the MongoDB is fully occupied by every single query on 100%, therefore casting all of them at once can be even worse as it has to swap between all the queries.

Comment: I wrote rhis code on Schema.statics.function, so “this” in the code is equal to the model.   Sorry I cant provide the code, answered by mobile.